# no module named 'cart' when i go to admin

Tags: python, django

I've created an app 'cart' and trying to import it in another app's view.py file. when i go to browser and type

```
http://localhost:8000/admin/
```

it says "no module named cart' but it's working fine in my 'terminal'. worth mentioning that 'home' view is also working fine. problem is at 'admin'.
In my 'cart' app i've defined 'cart.py' where i've implemented a function as

```
def add_to_cart(request):
    postdata = request.POST.copy() .....
```

and in my 'catalog' app's  'views.py' file i am importing 'cart.py' from 'cart' app as

```
from cart import cart
```

I've included 'cart' in 'installed_apps' also. All apps fall under the same project folder.

Comment: You'll need to give more details: what is your app structure? How are you importing that module? What exactly does the import code look like?

Comment: I've tried to make it understandable in the above edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing

```
from cart import cart
```

i wrote

```
import cart
```

and it worked fine for me. thanks